# How to mock a File with a big size in JavaScript for testing purposes?

Tags: javascript, file, jestjs

I've implemented a test case for my upload component which shows error if `file.size` more than 1 mb.

Is there a way to monkeypatch file size with `jest` or just js for getting test failing without creating the file like this?

```js
const file = new File(
  [new Blob(['1'.repeat(1024 * 1024 + 1)], { type: 'image/png' })],
  'darthvader.png'
)
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can simply use `Object.defineProperty` to override the original getter, it's configurable:

```js
const file = new File([""], 'darthvader.png');
Object.defineProperty(file, 'size', { value: 1024 * 1024 + 1 })
console.log( file.size ); // 1048577
```

Comment: I like this way, thanks. The only downside is TypeScript complaining when using `Object.defineProperty`

Comment: thanx:) nice answer!

Comment: How much MB is 1048577 ?

Comment: @Ahmadreza 1MiB + 1 byte

Comment: If you tried this and it didn't work, try adding `configurable: true` to your options (third) argument for `Object.defineProperty`

So you'd get something like:

`Object.defineProperty(file, 'size', { value: 1024 * 1024 + 1, configurable: true })`